# Solve the system by RREF

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

> Solve the system
>
> $$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{r@{}r@{}r@{}r@{}r}
> >   x_1 & -    x_2 &  - 6 x_3 & = & -5 \\
> >2 x_1 &  - 2 x_2 &  - 4 x_3 & = & -8 \\
> >2 x_1 &          & + 8 x_3 & = & 3  
> >\end{array} \right.$$
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\\\\\\\end{bmatrix} +s \begin{bmatrix}\\\\\\\end{bmatrix}$$

**My work so far**

I solved the RREF form to get

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&\frac{1}{2}\\0&1&0&4\\0&0&1&\frac{1}{4}\end{bmatrix}$$

My assumption would be the row reduced form says

\begin{align*}
x_1 & =\frac{1}{2}\\
x_2 & =4\\
x_3 & =\frac{1}{4}\\
\end{align*}

To get

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\4\\\frac{1}{4}\end{bmatrix} +s \begin{bmatrix}\\\\\\\end{bmatrix}$$

However, I'm unsure where to go from here. How would I get the solution for the $+s$ column? Also, is my work correct so far?

Comment: your solution is the only one

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for that! Would the $+s$ typically be used when the following RREF form is given, by adding $x_4$ and $x_5$ together? I just want to see if I understand the process. $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&\frac{1}{2}&2\\0&1&0&4&3\\0&0&1&\frac{1}{4}&5\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: If you got 
$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&\frac{1}{2}\\0&1&0&4\\0&0&0&\frac{1}{4}\end{bmatrix}$, then answer would be $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\4\\\frac{1}{4}\end{bmatrix} +s \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$